# Specifying file path in macro - macro fails, but inlined version works

Tags: rust, rust-macros

I'm trying to write some macros to clean up boilerplate around my intros/headers, to enforce that I'm organizing things in the same way, and to have a one-spot place to mandate any changes to such. I wanted to write one for organizing tests.

The structure I've settled on is for unit tests to go in a "test" sub-directory within a module's parent folder. So, for a leaf module `general.rs`, the header looks like:

```
#[cfg(test)]
#[path = "test/general_test.rs"]
mod general_test;
```

I'm trying to generate this via macro call:

```
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! declare_tests {
    ($mod_name : ident) => {
        #[cfg(test)]
        #[path = concat!("test/", stringify!($mod_name), ".rs")]
        mod $mod_name;
    };
}
```

But this fails:

```
crate::declare_tests!(general_test);
unresolved module, can't find module file: general/general_test.rs, or general/general_test/mod.rsrust-analyzerE0583
```

But if my IDE inlines it to inspect the problem, the problem goes away:

```
crate::declare_tests!(general_test);
```

inlines as

```
#[cfg(test)]
#[path = concat!("test/",stringify!(general_test),".rs")]
mod general_test;
```

which inlines as

```
#[cfg(test)]
#[path = "test/general_test.rs"]
mod general_test;
```

which works.

I think maybe my IDE (vscode) is doing these in the wrong order, but I can't tell what the right order would be?

Curious what's up with the inlining, but of course a better solution overall would also be welcome. (I plan to integrate this with `std::module_path!` to further reduce boilerplate/standardize, once I get this step working.)

EDIT:

With some experimentation:

```
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! declare_tests_helper {
    ($mod_path : expr, $mod_name : tt) => {
        #[cfg(test)]
        #[path = $mod_path]
        mod $mod_name;
        
    };
}
...
crate::declare_tests_helper!("test/general_test.rs", general_test);
```

works, tho doesn't help me as much as I'd like - I still can't pass another macro's result as an argument, because the outer macro is expanded first.

I'm wondering if it's possible to do this with a procedural macro, and (hopefully) greater control over order of execution?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use `concat!` in a `#[path]` attribute.

```
#[path = concat!("test/", "general_test", ".rs")]
mod general_test;
```

```
error: malformed `path` attribute input
 --> src/main.rs:6:1
  |
6 | #[path = concat!("test/", "general_test", ".rs")]
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ help: must be of the form: `#[path = "file"]`
```

Telling your IDE to inline the `concat!` macro is not what the compiler does when evaluating the `#[path]` attribute. In general, macros are evaluated by the outside-inward; so the `concat!` is not evaluated before the `#[path]` starts trying to use it.

Running function-like macros eagerly inside attributes macros only happen in limited circumstances. See [this PR](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/83366) for more info on allowing `#[doc = include!(...)]` but it mentions *"the attributes `path`, ... do not support this"*. And see [this issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/87681) for `#[path]` to support it.

Comment: Would a procedural macro have some power to solve this? I ask because with some experimentation, I found that I can create an artifical `#[path = $path_name]` call so long as `$path_name` is an argument to the macro, so it seems like if I could make a macro that generated the `expr` before calling, it would work (and I think procedural macros give you that control over order of execution?)

Comment: @EdwardPeters Yes. I think a procedural macro *would* be able to do this since you can do the string concatenation yourself before constructing the `#[path]` attribute with it.

Comment: Thanks, got it working! See other answer if you're curious.

Answer (score 1):

It's not pretty but it works! (My first proc macro, sure it's not ideal.)

```
#[proc_macro]
pub fn test_setup(_item: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {
    let first = _item.into_iter().next().unwrap();
    let id = match first{
        TokenTree::Ident(ident) => ident.to_string(),
        _ => panic!("Needed identifier"),
    };

    let imports = format!{"#[cfg(test)]
    #[path = \"test/{id}_test.rs\"]
    mod {id}_test;"};
     let statement = imports.parse().unwrap();
     statement
}
```

Use site:

```
proc_macros::test_setup!(general);
```

The original case wasn't working because the outer macro `#[path = <>]` was expanded first, and saw the un-expanded declarative macros. With procedural macros you can control the order of execution and actually generate the `#[path]` call with the arguments in place.